# Количество цифр без символов Regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

При проверке регулярное выражение не должно пропускать  не более 6 цифр

```
^(?!.*[0-9|\s]{6})(.*)$
```

не пропускает

```
123456
12345 6
```

но почему то пропускает

```
12345aa6
```

Comment: пробовали `([0-9|\s]{6})(.*)`. и еще, пробел входит в эти 6 цифр или отдельно?

Comment: А что вам мешает развернуть условие на уровне используемого языка программирования? Тогда можно будет использовать менее запутанное `^\d{1,6}$`, отсекая все варианты под него подходящие.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы он пропускал цифры,если их обшее количество в строке менее 6 цифр. Есть возможность использовать только регулярные выражения

Comment: @RavshanYuldashev, оу... везде? т.е. `1ab2cd3ef45g+567` - совпадение, а вот `1qwerty23` уже нет? я правильно понял условие?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Да все верно.

Comment: @RavshanYuldashev, ну а допустим, выполнить поиск в строке по обычному `\d`, и проверить что (количество совпадений >=6) - ваш язык программирования тоже не позволяет? Ну или, скажем, предварительно удалить из строки все символы кроме цифр?

Comment: @RavshanYuldashev, первое предложение в своем вопросе сформулируйте однозначно, а не с двойным отрицанием!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот регулярное выражение, которое пропускает строку содержащую 5 и менее цифр

```
%^(?!(?:.*?\d){6})(.+)$%u
```

Пример https://regex101.com/r/aP8yZ8/1

Comment: `1ab2cd3ef45g+567` скажем пропустило )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, нагло врете! Вставляю вашу строку в окно теста https://regex101.com/r/aP8yZ8/1, строка не выделяется и не попадает в matches.

Comment: дык по условию то как-раз и должна была попасть - в ней в совокупности 6 или более цифр )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, прочитайте коммент ТС `мне нужно чтобы он пропускал цифры,если их обшее количество в строке менее 6 цифр.` потому что тут `При проверке регулярное выражение не должно пропускать не более 6 цифр` без бутылки не поймешь, что написано.

Comment: у вас получилось, что если (общее количество цифр в строке >=6) - выражение всё равно не срабатывает. А по условию - должно..

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, по какому условию? Даже из кривой регулярки автора видно, что ему нужна вся строка в результате работы регулярного выражения, если в строке меньше 6 цифр. Отрицание там стоит, в регулярке-то! + его комментарий уточняющий на который я вам указал.

Comment: в ответе автора на мой вопрос, который я задал к указанному вами его же комментарию. Впрочем, автор данный ответ уже принял, поэтому видимо изначально задача была не совсем правильно понята.

Answer (score 0):

если значение начинается с цифр, тогда будет так

```
([0-9\s]{6})(.*)
```

[вот пример](https://regex101.com/r/qP1dM6/2)

Comment: а зачем здесь "или" (`|`), если `[]` уже означает "или"

Comment: @BOPOH согласень, упустил. Исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
my @l = qw/123456 1234f6 1a2b3c4d5e6f 111aaa222 abcdefghij12234 123456789 aaa12345_____6xxx/;
for (@l) {
    print "$_: matched\n" if /(\D*\d){6}/;
}
```

вывод:

```
123456: matched
1a2b3c4d5e6f: matched
111aaa222: matched
123456789: matched
aaa12345_____6xxx: matched
```

Выбирает строки, содержащие не менее 6 цифр в любых местах. Все, как обычно, гораздо проще. Без \D и \d будет соответсвенно `/[^0-9]*[0-9]{6}/`