# Как составить регулярное выражение для проверки емейла по спец.формату?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Не могу составить регулярное выражение на JS.

> Условие: адрес должен начинаться с большой буквы. Количество символов от начала и до знака собаки - не более 6-и. Из них могут быть цифры в количестве не более 3-х, а могут и отсутствовать. Все символы латинские и в нижнем регистре. Количесво символов после собаки и до точки - не более 4-х. Кол.символов после точки не принципиально.

Comment: а проверять не регулярным выражением - не вариант?

Comment: Да в том то и беда - что только регуляркой.

Comment: Откуда у вас такое ограничение, что только регуляркой. Это тестовое/учебное задание?

Comment: я не думаю что регуляркой можно сделать проверку на количество цифр не больше трёх

Comment: Все верно. Это учебное задание. После получасовой лекции я видимо должен щелкать регулярки аки белка орехи. Но не сложилось. Самостоятельное бдение над лёнджаваскрипт дает мизерный выхлоп.

Comment: Ну если сделать так нельзя, то тут бейся не бейся а всё равно не сделаешь... Но оно же и является ответом - сделать так нельзя. Но вот правда доказать или сказать со 100% уверенностью что нельзя я не могу....

Comment: Я думаю что можно сделать ту часть задания которую можно, а то что уже нельзя так и скзаать что нельзя или не знаю как.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин [можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473047/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-regex) сделать проверку на количество цифр

Comment: @MrFylypenko Да, вижу, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается так:

```
^[A-Z](?=([^0-9]*[0-9]){0,3}[^0-9]*@)[a-z0-9]{0,5}@[a-z0-9]{1,4}\.[a-z0-9]+$
```

PS: Надеюсь никогда не увидеть проверку по этим правилам в реальном коде.

Для проверки:

```css
input { outline: none; border: 1px solid; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^[A-Z](?=([^0-9]*[0-9]){0,3}[^0-9]*@)[a-z0-9]{0,5}@[a-z0-9]{1,4}\.[a-z0-9]+$" autofocus>
```

Comment: Таки точка важна. Валидным,согласно условиям, можно считать эмейл Ghf456@fghj.com И он, если пользоваться регуляркой предоставленной вами, не проходит валидацию.

Comment: Ага, вижу правку в вопросе. Ответ обновлён.

Comment: Но если не учитывать точку, то все работает. Спасибо за код!

Comment: Если проблема решена, надо принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: "PS: Надеюсь никогда не увидеть проверку по этим правилам в реальном коде." Извиняюсь за оффтоп, но почему?

Comment: Да потому что это жесть и реальные адреса этой регулярке не соответствуют. Знаешь как бесит, когда тратишь 3 часа на отправку формы из-за того, что email'ы валидацию не проходят? Там была шикарная проверка, которой из потенциальных 11 реальных адресов соответствовали только 3.